# strange query in mysql.log

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I found some strange query in mysql logs(general_log_file)

`Query SET SESSION sql_mode =
                    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                    @@sql_mode,
                    "STRICT_ALL_TABLES,", ""),
                    ",STRICT_ALL_TABLES", ""),
                    "STRICT_ALL_TABLES", ""),
                    "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,", ""),
                    ",STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", ""),
                    "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES", "")`

Can anyone explain what is this?
i am using 
Centos(7) + mariadb(5.5.56) + codeigniter(3.1.4)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query disables [strict sql mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) in MySQL / MariaDB on session level (e.g. for the current connection), thus reducing MySQL's compliance with the sql standards.